# Compiling ImageMagick with special path to librairies

Tags: compiling, php, imagemagick

I have been compiling ImageMagick 3.1.2 with the following options

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/imagick-3.1.2/ --with-php-config=/usr/local/php-5.3.13/bin/php-config --with-imagick=/usr/local/ImageMagick-6.8.8-6/ --libdir=/usr/local/apache/lib/
```

This is working great but I would like to put all librairies (libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2, libjpeg.so.62 ....) needed for imagick.so in one folder such as /usr/local/apache/libs

Then I would export the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/apache/lib:"

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

As my experience with compilation talk you could try this :

**edited version Try it in a new terminal**

```
 export LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS" -Wl,-blibpath:/usr/local/apache/lib" 
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/imagick-3.1.2/ --with-php-config=/usr/local/php-5.3.13/bin/php-config --with-imagick=/usr/local/ImageMagick-6.8.8-6/ --libdir=/usr/local/apache/lib/
```

And eventually complete your LDFLAGS with other things you could need.
Then your binary file will only use `/usr/local/apache/lib` to check for libraries you can test with `ldd your_binary` to check if libraries are find or not and where they are find.
I already manage to compile `proftpd` like this with both `gcc` and IBM `xlc`.

**notes**
As a side note I would say you should not use this too much and only when requested for real issue because it's way harder to debug and maintain and if your systems has different kernel or version, the libraries might not work.

Comment: Thank you. I tried but I got "/usr/bin/ld: invalid BFD target `libpath:/usr/local/apache/lib'" errors. I need this because I want to deploy this app in a chroot, and thus this is more easy to deploy if all libs are in my apache package.

Comment: @Hugo see the edit, You should not remove the path of all library during compilation

Comment: I tried the following : export LDFLAGS="-L/lib64/:/usr/lib64/:/usr/local/ImageMagick-6.8.8-6/lib/ -Wl,-blibpath:/usr/local/apache/lib" but didn't worked. For php I used the en variable PHP_RPATHS

Comment: @hugo do you already manage to compile it and how ?

Comment: @Hugo I add again your lib-dir option but it should not be a problem though according to http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/install.html LDFLAGS is set correctly

Comment: I manage to compile imagick without any issue If I don't specify export LDFLAGS maybe I am exporting wrong Path ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13264/discussion-between-kiwy-and-hugo)